# How to convert utc to utc+1 in javascript

Tags: javascript, time, timing

I got this value from a server `06:21:00` but the real time in `07:21:00` which is one hour later. I think the value is in UTC and I have to change it to UTC+1. so that my code can get the time and change it to UTC+1 and one hour will be added automatically.

Process: I will get the value from Server then pass it to my javascript code and the js code will change it to UTC+1 (which one hour will be added) and show the value.

How can I convert the gotten value to UTC+1 (TimeZone Berlin)

Second Question: I wrote the new Date().toUTCString() and the result it shown in english, can I show the result in germany ? like the week days?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please post the code that you are using so that we may better assist you.

Comment: What, exactly, is the value you get from the server?

Comment: this is the value `06:21:00` and I need to add one hour to it, because in my county, we have the utc+1 not the utc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for?

It will take the timestamp from the server in UTC and convert it appropriately to a date object where you can get the time back in your local timezone.

From there, you can map the numerical representation of the day and the month index to their German day and month abbreviations and put manually build a time string.

```js
let time = '06:21:00';
let date = new Date();
date.setUTCHours(...time.split(':'));

let days = ['Mo', 'Di', 'Mi', 'Do', 'Fr', 'Sa', 'So'];
let months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'März', 'Apr', 'Mai', 'Juni', 'Juli', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Okt', 'Nov', 'Dez'];

let str = `${days[date.getDay()-1]} ${months[date.getMonth()]} ${date.getDate()} ${date.getFullYear()} ${date.toTimeString()}`;

console.log(str);
```

Comment: You are very welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a JS-Pro so I don't think my code is beautiful but it works !

```js
h = "06:21:00".split(":")
n = (parseInt(h[0]) + 1) % 24
if (n.length = 1){
  n= "0" + n;
}
result = n + ":" + h[1] + ":" + h[2]
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks, It is very cool, the way you wrote the code. Thanks man!